# Set an RGB value and compare it another

Tags: javascript, rgb, phaser-framework

I am making a top-down racing game using Phaser as the framework and JavaScript and the language. I want to be able to tell the difference between two colours, so that if the car is off the track I can make it slow down. So far, I have the following code for this particular issue:

```
    var currentMatCol = bmd.getPixelRGB(Math.round(car1.x), Math.round(car1.y));
    var roadMatCol = RGB(0, 0, 0);
```

The first line gets the RGB value of what ever colour the car is on, black or white. The second line is where I'm struggling. I know that the road colour is black, so when the car is not on rgb 0 0 0, I want to slow it down, as if it's on grass or sand.

As I said the track in black, and the background is white. I have printed out the above lines to see what it shows, the first line is correct and shows what I want it to, but the second line does not.

I have an if statement to come after this, would look something like:

```
    if (currentMatCol == roadMatCol)
    {
      //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
      //set speed to very slow
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Apologies if I have not explained this well, it's hard to explain without showing it.

Comment: try `console.log(currentMatCol)` to undestand what's going on. possibilities are: `if (currentMatCol.color == roadMatCol.color)`, or `.color32` or you can use `.r` (red), `.g` and `.b` to compare just the color channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getPixelRGB` returns an object with component colors as properties (among other data)

see http://phaser.io/docs/2.2.2/Phaser.BitmapData.html#getPixelRGB

Looking at the documentation there doesn't seem to be a function `RGB` but you can build you "color" object easily

```
roadMatCol = {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0};
```

Of course you cannot compare two objects directly but you'll have to compare the color components separately.

So your code will became:

```
var currentMatCol = bmd.getPixelRGB(Math.round(car1.x), Math.round(car1.y));
var roadMatCol = {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0};

if( currentMatCol.r == roadMatCol.r &&
    currentMatCol.g == roadMatCol.g &&
    currentMatCol.b == roadMatCol.b )
{
  //do nothing
}
else
{
  //set speed to very slow
}
```

In genaral when comparing two colors, `c1` `c2`, you have to access their color components r, g, b (assuming they're represented in the RGB color space).

---

As a final note I think your approach to the problem (is the car onroad or offroad) could be better by checking the position of the car instead than looking at the background color.

Comment: That makes sense, however, that's not the issue I'm having. `var roadMatCol = RGB(0, 0, 0);` is the line that is causing my issue. I'm trying to set the road colour to black, so that if the RGB value of where the car is isn't 0, 0, 0, then the car will slow down. I know how to make it slow down with the if statement, but I'm unsure of how to set the road colour to black.

Comment: I edited the asnwer. See if it is more clear now. I think the problem is you don't have a `RGB` function. Even if you have it (maybe I missed something from the documentation) you cannot compare `currentMatCol == roadMatCol` because they are two objects and the comparison would always fail. You have to compare color components separately.

Comment: That's brilliant, that has worked perfectly! However, when the car hits white, it stops. In the `else` part of the `if` statement, I have `car1.body.velocity = -200;` I would've thought this would work, any suggestions on why the car stops?